# Convergence of $\sum_{n}\frac{q_n}{n}$, where $(q_n)$ enumerates $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

This problem is from a book reviewed Sep. 2020 Notices of AMS.

> Rational numbers in $[0,1]$ are countable.  Can they be ordered as $(q_n)_n$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q_n}{n}$ converges?

My belief is no, since half the rationals are in the upper half of the interval, the tail of the sum will always have half of its terms $\gt \frac{1}{2n}$ implying divergence.  I am having difficulty in making this rigorous.

Comment: My impression is that it is possible.  You keep choosing lots of small $q_n$'s while you wait for $n$ to grow and then you pick a sporadic large $q_n$.

Comment: I don't understand the current close vote: *"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."* The OP's question seems very clear and focused to me?

Comment: I cannot see close votes yet but if what @ClementC. says is true then I'm deeply worried.  This is one of the most interesting question I've seen in days!

Comment: @Ruy half of the rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ are in the interval $[1/2,1]$ so you can't avoid larger numbers as you describe.

Comment: This comment does not make the OP clearer (at least to me).

Comment: @JCAA  All I said was that the rational numbers in the interval [0,1] can be divided into two sets of equal size in interval [0,1/2] and [1/2,1].  Therefore the tail of any sum will have half its elements from each interval.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, I think hexomino's answer says it all but it may perhaps help our intuition to think that you may alternate back and forth between picking thousands of  $q_n$'s in $[0,1/2]$ then only one in $[1/2,1]$, and you will neatly end up picking all of them.  The denominators of the large $q_n$'s will be so big that the series will end up converging.

Comment: @Ruy I am still troubled.  The split at 1/2 was just for convenience.  It could be made at any c > 0, and hexamino's answer would have to be true for every such c..

Answer (score 13):

Ruy makes a good point in the comments you could possibly formalise it as follows.

Consider any ordering of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and remove those elements of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer which is not a positive power of $2$.

This leaves the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Then define $$ q_n =  \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  a_{\log_2 n}, \text{ if n is a positive power of 2}\\
                  \frac{1}{n}, \text{ otherwise}\\
                \end{array}
              \right.$$

This will imply that $$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q_n}{n} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} + 1$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like this can be slightly modified to generalize to any decreasing function $f$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) = 0$, instead of $1/n$ (i.e., $\sum_n q_n f(n)$). Is that correct?

Comment: @hexamino  I guess I wasn't clear enough in my statement.  $q_n$ are the rational numbers in some order, NOT functions of the rational numbers.

Comment: @hexamino    What happened to all the rationals m/n where n is not a power of 2 and m > 1?

Comment: @herb the result is correct as you get all the rationals except the $1/n, n \ne 2^k$ in a sequence $a_m$ and then you insert $a_1$ at $2$, $a_2$ at $4$, $a_3$ at $8$, $a_m$ at $2^m$ so all those get inserted but farther and farther, while at the rest of the $n$ you just insert the respective $1/n$

Comment: @Conrad  I don't understand what hexamino is doing.  For example, where does 3/5 go?

Comment: wherever it appears in the $a_n$ sequence you start with - remember first you number in a sequence all the rationals in $[0,1]$ except the $1/n, n \ne 2^k$ - so for example in the standard numbering (skipping $1/3,1/5$ as noted) $0/1, 1/1, 1/2, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5$ etc $3/5$ would be $7$th so would go on the $2^7$ place in $q_n$; hence $q_n$ would look like $ 1/1, 1/3, 1/2, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 2/3, 1/9, 1/10..., 1/15, 1/4, 1/17, 1/18,...1/31, 3/4,1/33,..1/65, 2/5...$, so $3/5$ would be after $1/127$ and would be followed by $1/129$

Comment: @ClementC, please see below a proof of your conjecture.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $3/5$ will be part of the $a_n$. The $a_n$ includes everything that is not of the form $1/n$

Comment: @ClementC. Apologies for my earlier comment, I completely misinterpreted.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a proof of  the conjecture made by @ClementC, with an improvement suggested by @TSF.

**Theorem**. Given any bounded function $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R_+$ admitting a subsequence $\{f(n_k)\}_k$ that converges to zero,
there is an enumeration $\{q_n\}$ of the rationals in $[0,1]$ such that
$$
  \sum_nq_nf(n)<\infty.
  $$

*Proof*. By hypothesis there are arbitrarily small elements in the range of $f$ so we may
choose an infinite subset $N_1\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n\in N_1}f(n)$ converges.  By discarding infinitely
many elements from $N_1$, if necessary, we may assume that
$$
  N_2:=\mathbb N\setminus N_1
  $$
is also infinite.

Furthermore  let $Q_1$ be the set of rationals defined by
$$
  Q_1=\{1/2^n: n\in \mathbb N\},
  $$
and let $Q_2$ be the complement of $Q_1$ in $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

All sets so far defined are countably infinite, so there are bijections
$$
  \alpha :N_1\to Q_2,
  $$
$$
  \beta :N_2\to Q_1.
  $$
The union of $\alpha $ and $\beta $ is therefore a bijection,
$$
  \gamma :\mathbb N\to  \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]
  $$
which is
the enumeration we are looking for, that is, $q_n=\gamma (n)$.
We then have  that
$$\begin{align}
  \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} q_nf(n) &=
  \sum_{n\in N_1} \gamma (n)f(n) +   \sum_{n\in N_2} \gamma (n)f(n) \\&=
  \sum_{n\in N_1} \alpha (n)f(n) +   \sum_{n\in N_2} \beta (n)f(n) \\&\leq
  \sum_{n\in N_1} f(n) +   \|f\|_\infty\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} 1/2^n < \infty.
  \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align}
  $$

Comment: I get it!  $N_1$ and $Q_1$ are sparse sets, but still infinite, so $N_1$ gets matched with most of the points $(Q_2)$ and the sum converges, because of $N_1$.   Similarly the other pair converges because of $Q_1$.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Thanks for a very interesting question. I'd be curious to know the title of the book reviewed in the Notices where this problem comes from.

Comment: Thanks for this! I thought monotonicity of f would be needed, but I guess I was wrong - will check tomorrow!

Comment: I don't think you need $f_n$ to go to $0$. You just need it to be bounded and have a summable subsequence. For this the latter it's enough to assume that there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which goes to $0$.

Comment: @TSF, you are right.  Assuming you allow me to I edited to include your suggestion.

Comment: @Ruy Book -  "Bicycle or Unicycle: A collection of Intriguing Mathematical Puzzles"  by Velleman and Wagon.